# Im using getTooltipContent in ag-grid (29.1.0) , is this deprecated how do i make tooltip work?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ag-grid

is there any replacement of getTooltipContent, seems like this is not working in ag grid

```
getTooltipContent={(e) => {

const data = e.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(e.rowIndex)?.data;

return data && e.column.colId === 'status' && showHealthCheckError(data)

                            ? `${i18next.t('NETWORK_SERVICE.HEALTH_CHECK.FAILED_MSG')}`
                            : null;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tooltipValueGetter` instead, below is an example from official docs

[tooltip aggrid docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-tooltip/#showing-blank-values)

```
const toolTipValueGetter = (params: ITooltipParams) => ({
  value: params.value,
});

...
{
  headerName: 'Athlete Col 2',
  field: 'athlete',
  minWidth: 150,
  tooltipComponent: CustomTooltip, // - can be removed if needed
  tooltipValueGetter: toolTipValueGetter,
},
...
```

Comment: hi @Naren Murali thanks for the suggestion but when i tried the solution given by you, I'm facing  below error 

 https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/4567

i think this is a open bug and solution is not provided yet, correct me if am wrong in any case

Comment: @arpithamysuru94 console.log the params.value and check what the object is, then get the respective property and show it on the tooltip. Please share the output of params.value in the question also!

Comment: I think tooltip value getter issue is not solved from community yet..
github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/4567 ( link for a open issue)

whatever we try,  it returns [object object ] as a output..